# Call MessageBox from async thread with Form1 as parent

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

After clicking `button1` placed on `form1`, program is checking if the new version is available (via internet), but doing this in the new thread (not to freeze the form during check).
When the new version is found or not, the appropriate `MessageBox` is shown, but it has no parent (because it was called from the thread, not directly from the `form1`).

How to make the `MessageBox` display with `form1` as a parent?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => { MessageBox.Show(this, "text"); }));
```

This will switch to main thread and show MessageBox with `form1` parent.

Comment: This gives me a lot of compilation errors (ie. Error 1 Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer)

Comment: Instead `this` use instance of your form1

Comment: How do you get the DialogResult here though? Invoke returns an object, and it is null.

Comment: @StealthRabbi: See my answer for that particular scenario.

Answer (score 15):

While the selected answer provides a nice way of displaying the `MessageBox` from an asynchronous thread, it doesn't handle the case where you want to retrieve the `DialogResult` from that particular `MessageBox` being shown.

If you are looking to return a `DialogResult` from the invoked `MessageBox` displayed on top of the `Form`. Then you need to use the [`Func`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) delegate instead of the `Action` delegate.

`Action` delegates always return void while `Func` has a return value.

Here is a little method that I devised to handle this particular scenario:

```
private DialogResult BackgroundThreadMessageBox(IWin32Window owner, string text)
{
   if (this.InvokeRequired)
   {
      return (DialogResult) this.Invoke(new Func<DialogResult>(
                             () => { return MessageBox.Show(owner, text); }));
   }
   else
   {
      return MessageBox.Show(owner, text);
   }
}
```

Although this isn't typically considered best practice or design it will work in a pinch.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would a better practice/design be?

Answer (score 5):

```
  if ( Form1.InvokeRequired ) {
            Form1.Invoke((Action)delegate{MessageBox.Show(Form1,"Hello");});
        }
```

Comment: In THIS case, since `MessageBox` is always called from another thread, using `if ( Form1.InvokeRequired )` is useless here.

Comment: if it is always, than agree

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [backgroundworker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   //Helper thread: Long during task
}

private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //We're in the main thread: Show your messagebox
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was in another class and had a reference for a textbox, so I used the code below:

```
_txtResultado.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate ()
{
    MessageBox.Show("My message!");
}));
```