# How does MsgBox() affect the exection of the VB.NET program?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I have an old **VB6** application which I am reworking to **VB.NET** and the previous programmer set this sort of thing when validating **MaskedTextBox** components:

```
MsgBox("My message")
b = True
myField.Focus()
```

Basically, a message box is open and if the validation failed the focus should get to other myField text component.

I changed the **Enter** event to **GotFocus** and now when the validation fails I am stuck on the current text field forever. I cannot even close the window because of the constant message box that appears.

I fixed the problem on **GotFocus** by moving the other statements above the **MsgBox()** command.

Yes it works well now, but really want to understand how does **MsgBox** affects the execution of the program?

Comment: `MsgBox` will halt execution until an action has been selected, which is helpful when you want to be getting `DialogResult` from one, for example asking a questions and retrieving a Yes or No value.

Comment: Please use the right tags.  There is no VB6 question here, and porting code to a different language is not an "upgrade."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN:

> Displays a message window, also known as a dialog box, which presents
>   a message to the user. It is a modal window, **blocking other actions in**
>   **the application** until the user closes it. A MessageBox can contain
>   text, buttons, and symbols that inform and instruct the user.

I can only guess it was either used for debugging or to give out an error message to the user.

If it was for an error message this might help: [Call MessageBox from async thread with Form1 as parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349524/call-messagebox-from-async-thread-with-form1-as-parent)

Comment: It is mostly used for validating input data, so no debbuging purposes. I now use Try/Catch for debugging. Should I still use MsgBox for validating data or there is a better approach?